# UICollectionView inside UICollectionViewCell trouble in getting scroll touch

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have implemented `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell` (both from left to right:Horizontal scrolling) everything works fine. The trouble is that when the last cell in the `innercollection` is scrolled the outside `UICollectionView` gets the touches and gets scrolled accordingly to left or right (happens for first and last cell).

How can I avoid this scroll that happens by default.

Answer (score 0):

if your custom `UICollectionViewCell XIB` file looks something like this at the the root (see the icon next to the Data Entry Matrix View, which is the name for my `UICollectionViewCell subclass`), then you will have the same problem:

[image]

The solution is to add a proper UICollectionViewCell class to the XIB, then move all the subviews under the existing Data Entry Matrix View into it, delete the old root, then reconnecting the Outlets. The end result looks like this:

[image]

You can see the different icon used - that's what you want. Once you would change your XIB like this the events were passed through.

In the raw XIB file (view as Source), the non-working version introduced the root element as

```
<view ...>
```

whereas the working version changed that root element to

```
 <collectionViewCell ...>
```

Comment: Hi Karim, I have the hierarchy the same way like your images with the correct UITableviewcell in Xib. I even checked the raw xib file which even shows me CollectionViewcell as root. What else could the problem?

Comment: May be you have some problem going on in your cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: I am very sure this is something to do with the internal implementation but i do not know how to overcome this feature

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the `innercollection` first react to pan gesture. This is easily done in code main collection code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [collectionView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:cell.innercollection.panGestureRecognizer];

    return cell;
}
```